# Finding the maximums of sets of items by an indexing array with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, vector

I have a numpy vector of shape (a,1) and I want to find the maximums of sets of items in that array with a precomputed index array. Should output a vector shape (b,1) where there a b different sets and each element is the maximum of a set from the initial vector.

Example:

`a = array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])`

`indices = [[0],[1,3],[1,4]]`

`[[1],[2,4],[2,5]]`

`output = array([[1],[4],[5]])`

I've tried multiplying the initial array by a matrix form of the indices (where the element is 1 if it's in the indices else 0) but that's inefficient. I've tried indexing the initial array and then taking the maximum but constructing the output array becomes ugly and similarly time-consuming.

What's the best approach? Preferably something using numpy functions, as performance is crucial.

Comment: `indices` can never be a numpy array, because it's not square.  I suspect a simple loop is nearly optimal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can improve very much on brute force:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
indices = [[0],[1,3],[1,4]]

l = [a[s].max() for s in indices]
output = np.array(l).reshape(-1,1)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[1]
 [4]
 [5]]
```